# Feed Deep Features to Machine learning Classifiers (Random forest )

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I want to feed my CNN deep features to the traditional classifier i.e random forest I dont wanna use MLP(Multi-layer-perceptron) to classify my problem but need other classifier to solve this problem for me. I have data of images. We cannot feed unstructured data to Machine Learning classifiers. I want to  first extracting deep features from CNN (Conv2d , activation,Maxpooling layers) than want to  take out image data into structured and down-sampled form  and than feed it to normal classifier. I my case I want to use random forest.
Here is my code..

I tried my code but this model is giving some error. I want to take my output after the flatten layer thats why I didn't add dense layers because I want to get only deep features not want to classify them. I find my problem's solution on google but didn't get any useful answers

```
model_1=Sequential()

model_1.add(Conv2D(96,(3,3),padding="valid"))
model_1.add(Activation("relu"))
model_1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding="valid"))

model_1.add(Conv2D(180 ,(3,3),padding="valid"))
model_1.add(Activation("relu"))

model_1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding="valid"))

model_1.add(Conv2D(200 ,(3,3),padding="valid"))
model_1.add(Activation("relu"))
model_1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding="valid"))


model_1.add(Flatten())

model_1.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model_1.fit(X_128,y_categorical,epochs=100)
x=model_1.predict(X_128)
```

by model.fit will learn the weights of conv2d and model.predict I think I got deep features I dint know I am true or not because I am getting error.
Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-3c769c68fc69> in <module>()
     18 
     19 model_1.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
---> 20 model_1.fit(X_128,y_categorical,epochs=100)
     21 x=model_1.predict(X_128)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    958             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    959             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 960             batch_size=batch_size)
    961         # Prepare validation data.
    962         do_validation = False

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    787                 feed_output_shapes,
    788                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 789                 exception_prefix='target')
    790 
    791             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    137                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    138                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 139                             str(data_shape))
    140     return data
    141 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected flatten_17 to have shape (33800,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

Thank you for taking my problem under consideration. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the model but with the underlying concept. A model needs to learn to generate good features. You are currently just passing them through `Flatten`.

What you actually need to do is add the Random Forest classifier as the last layer of your model. In keras, that will be possible by creating your own [custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). 
So the flow will be that flatten then pass it through your custom Random Forest layer to predict and then calculate the loss to backpropagate it through the network.

Comment: Is it possible to get good features from CNN and than after that apply it on different classifiers ? I want to ensemble classifiers and than pass my features and labels to predict the best result.

Comment: No matter what you want you will have to train your CNN for it to learn good features. The most practical and easiest solution for you would be to take a pre-trained model like Imagenet models and extract the features from its last layer.

Comment: Thank you @Raunaq I will try you suggestion. I want to clear one thing here. Last layer of any model basically use softmax activation with Dense layer (no of class) and through the last layer I get the probabilities of the the predicted class. Am i right? So last dense layer will give me features or Conv2d or Maxpool layer. Sorry I am confused about this. Searched on google but didnt find some useful answer..

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear. Just remove the last fully connected layer, which classifies into different labels.

Comment: Yaa ! I did so. Will you please go through the code I have given in question. Thank you! so nice of you

Comment: You did do so but that model hasn't been trained so it is useless. Get a pre-trained model, pass the image through it, extract the features from 2nd last layer and use it for your classifier.

Comment: Ahhh that whats I want to do.  lets see the code I am fitting my model by
model_1.fit(X_128,y_categorical,epochs=100)  this and trying to get my features of the same data by predicting the same X_128 array. So what thing I am doing wrong. Really Thank ful to you for helping me. Appreciated